# How to use RNN tensorflow to learning one-Dimensional Data? AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'batch'

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, batch-processing, deep-learning

The one-D data concludes 80 samples, with everyone is 1089 length. I want to use 70 samples to training and 10 samples to testing.

I am totally beginner in python and tensorflow, so I use the code which is processing image(which is two-dimension). Here is the code I use(all the parameters are pretty low for I just want to test the code):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import scipy.io as sc
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn, rnn_cell

# data read
feature_training = sc.loadmat("feature_training.mat")
feature_training = feature_training['feature_training']
print (feature_training.shape)

  feature_testing = sc.loadmat("feature_testing.mat")
   feature_testing = feature_testing['feature_testing']
   print (feature_testing.shape)

label_training = sc.loadmat("label_training.mat")
label_training = label_training['label_training']
print (label_training.shape)


label_testing = sc.loadmat("label_testing.mat")
label_testing = label_testing['label_testing']
print (label_testing.shape)


# parameters
learning_rate = 0.1
training_iters = 100
batch_size = 70
display_step = 10

# network parameters
n_input = 70  # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_steps = 100  # timesteps
n_hidden = 10  # hidden layer num of features
n_classes = 2  # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_steps, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

# Define weights
weights = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}


def RNN(x, weights, biases):

    # Prepare data shape to match `rgnn` function requirements
    # Current data input shape: (batch_size, n_steps, n_input)
    # Required shape: 'n_steps' tensors list of shape (batch_size, n_input)

    # Permuting batch_size and n_steps
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    # Reshaping to (n_steps*batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_input])
    # Split to get a list of 'n_steps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.split(0, n_steps, x)

    # Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
    lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)

    # Get lstm cell output
    outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Linear activation, using rnn inner loop last output
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']

pred = RNN(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    step = 1
    # Keep training until reach max iterations
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:
        batch_x, batch_y = feature_training.next_batch(batch_size)
        # Reshape data to get 28 seq of 28 elements
        batch_x = batch_x.reshape((batch_size, n_steps, n_input))
        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        if step % display_step == 0:
            # Calculate batch accuracy
            acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            # Calculate batch loss
           # loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            print ("Iter " + str(step*batch_size) + ", Training Accuracy= " +
                  "{:.5f}".format(acc))
        step += 1
    print ("Optimization Finished!")
# Calculate accuracy for 10 testing data
test_len = 10
test_data = feature_testing[:test_len].reshape((-1, n_steps, n_input))
test_label = label_testing[:test_len]
print ("Testing Accuracy:",
       sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_data, y: test_label}))
```

At last, it turns out the Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/xiangzhang/MNIST data test.py", line 92, in <module>
    batch_x, batch_y = feature_training.batch(batch_size)
    AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'next_batch'
```

I thought it must be related with the dimension of the data, but I do not know how to fix it. Please help me, thanks very much.

Comment: The title is   AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'next_batch'.  It makes me crazy, please help me.

Comment: What makes you think that the feature_training variable should have a next_batch function defined?

Comment: What do you expect `feature_training` to be?  Some `tensorflow` object?  The error says it's a `numpy` array.  If needed, explain to us what `next_batch` is supposed to do, and how it is defined.

Comment: @Aaron  I just want to use [feature_training] as the training samples to establish the RNN model and test it by the [featur_testing], but I do not know the exactly code, so that I copy this code from github example which is used to processing imagine classification. I may not need [next_batch] ,could you tell me how to revise the code?

Comment: @hpaulj I just want to use feature_training as the training samples to establish the RNN model, but I do not know the exactly code, so that I copy this code from github example which is used to processing imagine classification.  Specifically, I know this code is not suit for my 1-D data, but I do no know how to revise it. Could you tell me how to revise the code, or one samiliar example code?